# All inputs plus checkbox elements got selected in jQuery with input:text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with textareas,texts,checkboxes and buttons. I select elements as below:

```
$("#frmPersonalInfo :input:not(input[type=radio]):not(input[type=button])").each(function(){  
  //code here
});
```

When I omit the `not(input[type=radio])` then radio elements are being selected. I want to select the radio that has been checked (the active one) not all radio inputs. Is there a way to do this?
Radio HTML code is as follow:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" id="txtPersonalInfoMale" name="gender" value="1" />
<input type="radio" id="txtPersonalInfoFemale" name="gender" value="2" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might not be the best method but the below should work

```
  $("#frmPersonalInfo :input:not(input[type=radio]):not(input[type=button]),#frmPersonalInfo :input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){  
//code here
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `:checked` to select all the checked checkboxes,

```
$("#frmPersonalInfo :input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){  
  //code here
});
```

If you want to select some of input types then you can do it this way, you will need to customize it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/AStAT/2/)**

```
$("#frmPersonalInfo :input").not(':button').not(':text').filter(function(){
    if($(this).attr('type') == 'radio' && $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')
    return $(this);
}).each(function(){
   //Your code here
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return the not checked ones?

Comment: `Not checked` this seems wrong. I want to select the checked one.

Comment: Oh please @Adil, what about textboxes?? please be careful. your example does not select textboxes,textareas,select inputs.

Comment: This just selects active radio button, right? What about textboxes,textareas,select inputs??

Comment: @phpGeek, what _do_ you want to select?

Comment: Active radio and textboxes,textareas,hidden,select inputs. `NOT` all radios that this question has already covered.

Comment: @phpGeek I tried to accomplish what you need and updated my answer please tell me if it is still not what is required.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the effort Adil, @Vanamali's answer was what I was lookin' for.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what I want I did the following:

```
            var cnt=0;
            $("#frmPersonalInfo :input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){
                    personalInfoArr[cnt++]=$(this).val();
            });
            $("#frmPersonalInfo :input:not(input[type=radio]):not(input[type=button])").each(function(){
                    personalInfoArr[cnt++]=$(this).val();
            });
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score -2):

shouldn't it be like this? why all the :not ?

```
$("#frmPersonalInfo input[type=radio]:selected").each(function(){  
      //code here
});
```

dude,maybe i did not understand your question.
jQuery has a ":selected" selector.
you can find all the info here:

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: a valiant effort. But other than the fact that your solution is almost identical to @Adil's, `:selected` cannot be applied to radio controls. Radio controls are `checked', options in drop-downs are `selected`.

Comment: Dude, maybe you didn't understand the link you provided; and I quote, "`The :selected selector works for <option> elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio inputs; use :checked for them.`"